# Root compiliation error using Boost (Error suffix.hpp:496:)

Tags: c++, boost, root-framework

I'm using root to compile some C code which uses Boost and receive this error

```
Error: class,struct,union or type __int128 not defined
 /usr/include/boost/config/suffix.hpp:496:
```

I have seen this problem previously when using Cuda and boost but not root, can someone advise how to fix.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.0.04, boost 1_58 and root 5.34.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using nvcc? Boost has some problems with nvcc. 

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8048

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10418

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11852

If you are using nvcc, you should use a Boost version (1.60.0) that contains this fix: https://github.com/boostorg/config/pull/83

Comment: Hi no im not using nvcc

Comment: how are you "using ROOT to compile come C code"? I wouldn't recommend using ROOT as a compiler.

Comment: Do you mean that you use `root your_code.c+` to compile your code, or in the root command line `.L your_code.c+`? Or do you mean that you compile your code with a "more normal" c compiler (e.g. `gcc`) while using root in your code and compiler call, e.g. with `gcc $(root-config --cflags) your_code.c -c -o your_code.o` ?

Either way, a minimum working example would help (either you'll find the problem when creating it, or to share the code).